# How to calculate the number of edges and vertices of iterated line graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Given , a graph $G(V,E)$ , how do I calculate the number of edges and vertices of $L(G)$ ,  $L(L(G))$,$L(L(L(G)))$ , and further...

where $L(G)$ denotes the line graph of graph $G(V,E)$

My approach : - The number of vertices in $L(G)$ is equivalent to number of edges in $G$ ,each vertex of degree $k$ in the original graph $G$ creates $k(k-1)/2$ edges in the line graph .

But how to do the calculation for $L(L(G))$ and further.

Comment: This is a reduction of an ongoing contest problem.